# Get SpringLoaded to watch all classes of a project

Tags: java, spring-loaded

Is there a way to tell springLoaded to watch all classes of a project instead of a single class as shown in the how-to section ?

```
java -javaagent:<pathTo>/springloaded-{VERSION}.jar -noverify SomeJavaClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Omit SomeJavaClass. It's that simple

Edit: look up this [Using Spring loaded in spring mvc framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944042/using-spring-loaded-in-spring-mvc-framework)

Comment: I get the error: Syntaxe : java [-options] class [args...]    so it looks like "class" is mandatory

Comment: It's not mandatory or I could not use it in this way all the time. It depends how you are configuring JVM options. For example I set MAVEN_OPTS in batch script (because I have several modules to install) and it works perfectly